# Where do Google get canonical links of a one-page site?

Tags: seo, javascript, canonical-url, escaped-fragment

With my miserable JS knowledge I understand that the page originally has a line like this:

[image]

and then href parameter is changed via JS. Both SF and Deepcrawl are not able to see that change. Thus, all the pages have the same canonical.

The only solution I could think of is prerendering the page and using escaped fragments. In that case, does Google take canonical parameters from the original page or from the HTML snapshots? Anyone with this experience?

Comment: Can you use pushstate?

Comment: already using it?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing with trying to get a javascript rendered sites onto Google is not uncommon. Companies like Prerender.io solve it for you. If the URI doesn't change it's very difficult for Google to index.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. We are already considering using prerender.io or phantomjs. My only concern about using those services is that when the canonical on a page and the canonical on its snapshot contradicts. In such a case, I wonder which one will be taken into account by Googlebot.

Comment: That's a good question, I've never encountered that situation before so I've no idea! Sorry.